# Input_shape in 3D CNN

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have a dataset of 100000 binary 3D arrays of shape (6, 4, 4) so the shape of my input is (10000, 6, 4, 4). I'm trying to set up a 3D Convolutional Neural Network (CNN) using Keras; however, there seems to be a problem with the input_shape that I enter. My first layer is:

```
model.add(Conv3D(20, kernel_size=(2, 2, 2), strides=(1, 1, 1), activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_uniform', input_shape=(None, 6, 4, 4, 1)))
```

The error I receive is:

> ValueError: The last dimension of the inputs to `Dense` should be defined. Found `None`.

Still, when I replace None with an integer and I try to fit the model to my dataset the error I get is:

> ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential_13 is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: (10, 6, 4, 4)

What should be modified here?

Comment: Is there a specific reason that you want to use 3D convolution? `(6,4,4)` is valid for 2D convolution.

Comment: @Frightera Since my input data are volumetric I thought I should use 3D ConvNet. Is that not right?

Comment: Then what's the channel size in your case? 3D layer interprets your input as `6 x 4 x 4 x channels`.

Comment: @Frightera Let me check to see if I get this straight. So, you mean I should use a 2D ConvNet and consider the depth of 6 as the number of channels for my 4 by 4 binary matrices?  instead of a 3D ConvNet?

Comment: Your depth is 4 here unless you set `data_format = channels_first` in the convolution layer(OK for 2D conv). Or you can add channel dimension to the first input, by expanding dims, then it will have the shape `(6,4,4,1)`.

Comment: @Frightera Thank you for your kind help. I would appreciate it if you could elaborate on your last comment. I don't know how to implement those changes. Also, would it solve the problem if I prepare my dataset with the shape of (100000, 4, 4, 6)?

Comment: You can change the channel ordering. I explained it in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with dummy data:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.random.normal((100000, 6, 4, 4))
x.numpy().shape # (100000, 6, 4, 4) # 4 --> channel size by default
```

That will not work with 3D convolution:

```
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(2, 3, activation='relu', 
                           input_shape=(6, 4, 4, 1))(x)
print('After convolution', y.shape)
```

It will say `expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4 ...`. You need to add a channel dimension to that data. This can be simply done with:

```
x_expanded = tf.expand_dims(x, axis = -1)
print('Expand_dims shape', x_expanded.numpy().shape) # (100000, 6, 4, 4, 1)

y = tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(2, 3, activation='relu', 
                           input_shape=(6, 4, 4, 1))(x_expanded)
print('After convolution', y.shape) # (100000, 4, 2, 2, 2)
```

Or at the first time, you can use the data with 2D convolution:

```
x = tf.random.normal((100000, 6, 4, 4))
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', 
                           input_shape=(6, 4, 4))(x)
print('After convolution', y.shape) # (100000, 4, 2, 2)
```

You can also change the order of the channels in the convolution layer:

```
y = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(2, 3, activation='relu', 
                           input_shape=(6, 4, 4),
                           data_format="channels_first")(x) # --> 6 will be channels
print(y.shape) # (100000, 2, 2, 2)
```

Edit:

```
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv3D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 4, 4, 1)))

model(x_expanded).shape # TensorShape([100000, 4, 2, 2, 2])
```

Comment: I so much appreciate your help. Also, thank you for answering with details.
I guess there is something wrong with the syntax here. I tried your 3D ConvNet code but I get an error. Is it possible that you write it in a model.add(Conv3D format. Here is the error I get:
InvalidArgumentError: Value for attr 'T' of int64 is not in the list of allowed values: half, bfloat16, float, double ...

Comment: Can you try to cast your data to int32 or float32? I don't have any errors. See the edit.

Comment: Thank you so much. My data type is numpy.ndarray; however yours is tensorflow.python.framework.ops.EagerTensor. When I use your data type I receive no error. But in my case I upload my data as .npy file and use it as numpy.ndarray I receive the previous error.

Comment: Did you try that: `your_arr = your_arr.astype(np.float32)`.

Comment: It worked, thanks. However, I get this warning before the NN training:
WARNING:tensorflow:Model was constructed with shape (100000, 6, 4, 4, 1) for input KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(100000, 6, 4, 4, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name='module_wrapper_7_input'), name='module_wrapper_7_input', description="created by layer 'module_wrapper_7_input'"), but it was called on an input with incompatible shape (20, 6, 4, 4, 1).

Comment: In the input_shape parameter do not include sample size(100000) if you did. `(6,4,4,1)` should be fine itself. If that's not the issue, I need to see the model definition with your data shape.

Comment: Everything works perfectly right now. I appreciate your kind help. Just one question btw:
Is the depth still 4 in the following format?
model.add(Conv3D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 4, 4, 1)))
I try to add that argument to this Keras format but I get an error. (You had added that to the previous format.)

Comment: It should also work in that format too maybe you made a mistake. It is the last axis, in this case 1.

Comment: Np. Thanks for all your help. Just let me know how I can use that argument (data_format="channels_first") in the following layer:
model.add(Conv3D(2, 3, activation='relu', input_shape=(6, 4, 4, 1)))
It is important for me to have 6 as the depth. However, when I generate my arrays with the shape of (100000, 4, 4, 6) your code (P = tf.expand_dims(P, axis = -1)) yields the previous result (Expand_dims shape (10000, 6, 4, 4, 1)).

Comment: It should be passed in Conv3D layer, you can pass it right after the input_shape.